# Finding Letters in a String and comparing Chars (Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a basic program where it checks if a word is a palindrome, and I need to figure out how to do two things.

- How do I figure out how many letters are in a string?

and

- How do I compare two chars to see if they are the same?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: The [API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is your friend.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `StringBuilder` to reverse the string? Since this sounds like a homework assignment, I would guess not, but you can always do: `String s = "risetovotesir"; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s); boolean isPalindrome = s.equals(sb.reverse());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I figure out how many letters are in a string?

[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) in Java is immutable object which means it does not change. So the following code creates new string every time it is needed:

```
String s = "Hello";
s += " World";
```

After above introduction the answer to question nr 1 is

```
int len = s.length();
```

> How do I compare two chars to see if they are the same?

String has access method for its characters, that you can use to access and compare them:

```
char one = s.charAt(0);
char two = s.charAt(1);
if (one == two) {
   :
}
```

For your assignment I would recommend to use **public char[] toCharArray()** method and loop the array for accessing each character.

Comment: It concatenate strings, it is the same as  `s = s + " World"`

Answer (score 0):

1.) StringName.length() <- Java has a method that will return the length of the string
2.) charName == charName2 <- primitive type can use the comparison operator
You have some good ideas that will help you write a palindrome program. I will offer no hints though so you can figure it out. good luck. <-Taken (bad guy) voice

Comment: Length of the string or number of letters in string?